# Disabled cookies will logout ion_auth user after redirect in Facebook Canvas

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, ion-auth

I am using codeigniter and I have a controller that will login user or register them if they are not registered or prompt Facebook login if they are not logged into Facebook.

Now the problem I am having is that if cookies are disabled, the controller will log them in successfully (I var_dumped the $user and it was fine)  and then redirect them to another controller that will show the page where the user is somehow logged out (var_dump user will give empty array).

If I do the same thing outside the facebook canvas, its all good.

```
public function login_fb()
    {

        require './assets/fb_sdk/src/facebook.php';
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => 'app_id',
            'secret' => 'secret id',
            'cookie' => false // i tried it for true as well
        ));

        // See if there is a user from a cookie (even if cookies are disabled it works)
        $user = $facebook->getUser();

        if ($user) {
            try {
                // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)) . '</pre>';
                $user = null;
            }

            $f_id = $user_profile['id'];

 // log in user
                $identity = $f_id;
                $password = "some-password";
                $remember = TRUE; // remember the user
                $this->ion_auth->login($identity, $password, $remember);

                // update token
                $data = array (

                    'access_token'=> $token
                );
                $this->db->where ('username',$f_id);
                $this->db->update ('users',$data);

                $user_ion = $this->ion_auth->user()->row(); 
                //var dump on user_ion will give user information all good



    header('Location: '.base_url().'deals');
}
```

after the redirect, it loses all the login information and

```
$user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
```

will give an empty array. This all works fine if its not under the facebook canvas. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you keeping track of your PHP Sessions when cookies are disabled? Codeigniter (and PHP by default) uses a cookie to keep track of your PHP Session ID, so if you have cookies disabled, your will lose your session data.

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie on the form page where you have the login form. That way you can check if the cookie was set correctly **before** logging them in.

- User opens or clicks and gets to login page. Set a cookie, show the form view.
- User enters login information on the form, and clicks.
- Before anything else -- Check to see if the cookie was set -- if it was not set then give them an error page with cookies required message.

(ok i don't even know why i was looking at such an old question )